# Could not login with username: root, host: <host_ip>

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, ftp, sftp

I am trying to upload a file over `sftp` using laravel.

Here's SFTP configuration:

```
SFTP_HOST=X.X.X.X
SFTP_USERNAME=root
SFTP_PASSWORD=
SFTP_KEY_PATH=/root/usr/es_server.pem
```

config > filesystems.php

```
'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host'     => env('SFTP_HOST'),
        'port'     => 22,
        'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
        'root' => '/uploads/', 
        'privateKey' => env('SFTP_KEY_PATH'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'permPublic' => 0755,
        'directoryPerm' => 0755
    ]
```

This is working properly on my local, with the same `host` and `key`.

But from deployed server, I get this

```
"Could not login with username: root, host: x.x.x.x"
```

Logging into the deployed server, and connecting the `host` server over `sftp` is working for the `root` user and the `same key`.

```
root@dma:~# sftp -i es_server.pem root@x.x.x.x
Connected to x.x.x.x
sftp>
```

I checked for firewalls on the host server if it is blocking the deployed server but no blocks found.

What could be the issue? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Finally found the issue.

The application was denied the access to key path as defined in `SFTP_KEY_PATH`.

I set the path to some where the application can access the key.

In my case, `SFTP_KEY_PATH=/var/www/html/dma/es_key.pem`.